How to properly validate and sanitize URL input using express-validator in an Express.js application?
I am working on an Express.js project where I need to validate and sanitize user inputs for creating menu and submenu items. I am using express-validator for validation. However, I am facing an issue where the URL input is being escaped and stored incorrectly in my database (e.g., http:// becomes http:&#x2F;&#x2F;).
Here is my current code:
.post("/create/:infotype",
    [
        param("infotype").isString().isIn(["menu", "subMenu"]).withMessage("Invalid infotype"),
        body('name').trim().escape().isString().notEmpty().withMessage("Please provide a name for the menu/submenu"),
        body('url').trim().isString().notEmpty().withMessage("URL should be a string"),
        body('order').optional().isInt().withMessage("Order should be an integer"),
        body('show').optional().isBoolean().withMessage("Show should be a boolean"),
        body('menuId')
            .if((value, { req }) => req.params?.infotype === "subMenu")
            .notEmpty()
            .withMessage("Menu ID is required for submenus")
            .isInt()
            .withMessage("Menu ID should be an integer"),
    ],
    MenuSubMenuController.create,
)

I have updated the URL validation to use .isURL() to ensure it is a valid URL:
.post("/create/:infotype",
    [
        param("infotype").isString().isIn(["menu", "subMenu"]).withMessage("Invalid infotype"),
        body('name').trim().escape().isString().notEmpty().withMessage("Please provide a name for the menu/submenu"),
        body('url').trim().isString().notEmpty().isURL().withMessage("URL should be a valid URL"),
        body('order').optional().isInt().withMessage("Order should be an integer"),
        body('show').optional().isBoolean().withMessage("Show should be a boolean"),
        body('menuId')
            .if((value, { req }) => req.params?.infotype === "subMenu")
            .notEmpty()
            .withMessage("Menu ID is required for submenus")
            .isInt()
            .withMessage("Menu ID should be an integer"),
    ],
    MenuSubMenuController.create,
)

While this ensures the URL is valid, I am concerned about XSS attacks. How can I properly sanitize the URL and other inputs to protect against XSS while ensuring the URL is stored correctly in the database?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
